# Rails+passenger+nginx run app with url without :port

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I have a rails app... I installed chain: nginx+passenger and run rails server. But my trouble is that in browser i must to set up url like:

```
page.com:3000
```

but how to use only page.com?

I can't run command `passenger start -e=development -p=80` of user restriction....

My nginx conf file is such:

```
server {
        listen      80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;
        #root /home/prog/OnlineAuto/Shop/public;
        #passenger_enabled on;
        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;
        location / {
                root /home/prog/OnlineAuto/Shop/public;
                index  index.html index.htm;
                passenger_enabled on;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
}
```

So how can i get my rails app by domain without any port? (but run rails server on 3000 port)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to start Passenger on the same port that Nginx is using which is likely why you're getting an error.

I'm more familiar with Unicorn, but based on the documentation I've read, you shouldn't have to start Passenger in a separate process. With Passenger installed properly, I think you only need Nginx directives to make it work.

Configure your passenger_root and passenger_ruby in http block in `nginx.conf`, and then

```
http {
  passenger_root /<path_to_passenger_install>;
  passenger_ruby /usr/local/bin/ruby;

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name page.com;
    charset utf-8;
    root /www/page.com/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_spawn_method smart;
    rails_env development;
  }
}
```

Comment: path for public i get via pwd

Comment: Do you have any error logs from nginx that you could share? What version of passenger/rails/nginx are you using?

Comment: rails 3.2.8 passenger 3.0.19

Comment: also is it bad to use nginx+passenger or better nginx+unicorn?

Comment: Depending on linux distro, nginx logs can usually be found in `/var/log/nginx`. Look specifically at `error.log`.

Comment: hm, could find them on ubuntu 12.04(

Answer (score 0):

If you are using passenger here is what I had to use to get it working on www.mysite.com without using www.mysite.com:80 on a centos server:

In etc/httpd/conf the key was to uncomment the NameVirtualHost *:80 and change the * to my server's IP address. Make sure Listen 80 is uncommented. Also add your ip to the VirtualHost tag. It must be running on port 80, not 8080 or something of your choosing.

```
NameVirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:80  

Listen 80  

<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:80>
    ServerName www.mysite.com
    # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/public/
    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/public/>
       # This relaxes Apache security settings.
       AllowOverride all
       # MultiViews must be turned off.
       Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```